# Python QWebView: Accessing Network Resources

Tags: python, pyqt, webkit, pyqt4, qwebview

I am trying to access the network request urls with **QNetworkAccessManager**

From this example [Threading with webkit](https://webscraping.com/blog/Threading-with-webkit/), I have attached the NetWorkAccessManager to existing code, but the page simply doesn't load with my code.

```
import sys
from collections import deque # threadsafe datatype
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *
NUM_THREADS = 2 # how many threads to use

class Render(QWebView):
    active = deque() # track how many threads are still active
    data = {} # store the data

    def __init__(self, urls):
        QWebView.__init__(self)

        # I have Added the following code
        manager = Manager()
        page = self.page()
        page.setNetworkAccessManager(manager)

        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.urls = urls
        self.crawl()

    def crawl(self):
        try:
            url = self.urls.pop()
            print 'downloading', url
            Render.active.append(1)
            self.load(QUrl(url))
        except IndexError:
            # no more urls to process
            if not Render.active:
                # no more threads downloading
                print 'finished'
                self.close()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        # process the downloaded html
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        url = str(frame.url().toString())
        Render.data[url] = frame.toHtml()
        Render.active.popleft()
        self.crawl() # crawl next URL in the list

# I have Added the following class
class Manager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'entered network manager'
        QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
        self.finished.connect(self._finished)

    def _finished(self, reply):
        print 'finished network req event'
        url = reply.url().toString()
        print url.toUtf8()

app = QApplication(sys.argv) # can only instantiate this once so must move outside class
urls = deque(['http://www.google.com/', 'http://stackoverflow.com/'])
renders = [Render(urls) for i in range(NUM_THREADS)]
app.exec_() # will execute qt loop until class calls close event
```

What am I doing wrong in here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to add `self.setPage(page)` Before setting  `page.setNetworkAccessManager(manager)`